# Refunding return leg of Air France ticket in Business class

Tags: air-travel, international-travel

I would be flying from PRG-SIN in a couple of months in Business Class considering how much one way tickets cost in Y, but I was thinking, is it possible to book a return ticket and refunding the inbound flight.

Answer (score 1):

Looking very quickly at the fare tariff Air France has filed on PRG-SIN, the cheapest return fare in business class is 1777.00 EUR and the cheapest one-way fare is 1915.00 EUR. These figures exclude taxes, fees and surcharges.  The cheapest fare has a change fee of 240 EUR. Therefore the cost of cancelling the return flight would probably be 378 EUR, however I have not validated this information so please check before you purchase.

A better strategy is to consider your true itinerary here. Are you planning to fly to Prague to Singapore and never ever return to Europe? If you do plan to return to somewhere in Europe at some point, you might be better purchasing the actual itinerary you want to perform.

If you are determined to indulge in throw-away ticketing, your best strategy is to buy a return trip outbound in business class and return in cheapest economy. The fares may be combined to form round-trips on a half-round-trip basis, so the price would be half a business class return fare + half an economy class return fare. You may have to telephone AF to buy this as you cannot do it online. I can price that (inclusive of fees and tax) for about 1433 EUR.

Comment: That's before tax. I was wondering if I booked the outbound ticket in semi flexible J and the inbound in full fare, would the inbound be refundable? I wouldn't mind paying for J oneway since the price difference is so small.

Comment: @world.travelny Please see my updated answer for a cheaper suggestion. The whole itinerary would be repriced if you insisted on changing after departure, because the round-trip fare is not valid as a stand alone outbound without some kind of return.

Comment: Ah I have thought of that, didn't quite realize that fares become repriced after departure, thought I could refund the return leg without a fee. I was actually able to get that to price online for 38920 CZK or 1563 USD. Oh well, 15000 CZK is something right?

Comment: @world.travelny It's complicated because usually fully flown fares are not repriced. However that feeds back into whether you are entitled then to modify the other fares on the ticket without breaching the combinability provisions of the first fare component.

Comment: I apologize if this is too much to ask, but if I booked the outbound in semi flex business class and the return in fully flex, would the inbound be subject to the worser fare rules of the outbound?

Comment: @world.travelny I know what you're trying to do, but I don't think you're going to defeat the fare restrictions like this. The outbound component needs to be combined with an inbound component or it isn't valid, so (in my understanding) you can refund the return leg only if you buy a new return leg.

Comment: So if I flew the outbound, I wouldn't be able to refund the other ticket without a reprice?

Answer (score 1):

If you book a flexible fare, you could potentially modify or even cancel it. But I doubt that it will be 100% free. It usually depends on the fare purchased.

Another option would be to purchase an Y ticket and then apply for an upgrade. It might work and you would lose less if you can't be refunded on the return flight.